# The word "Meta" in the site name should be allowed to translate

Tags: feature-request, localization, russian-stackoverflow

As far as I see the word "Meta" in the site name from the main menu is not able to localize:

> [image: main menu]

Is it possible to make it translatable?

According to the post on ruSO.meta: [Как следует перевести термин "Meta"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/481) we need to translate it.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how how I feel about this, it is the actual name of the site not just a description... "Stack Overflow" isn't translatable is it?

Comment: @Cai I think "Meta" in this case is not a *part of the site's name*, but rather a *name of part of the site*. Like a name of the company's division, and should be able to translate.